# Iterate through python string starting at index

Tags: python, string, iterator, character

If I have a very long string (say 100 million characters), is there a way to iterate through the characters using something like `for c in str:` but starting a certain number of characters in? I'd prefer not to slice the string and use a subset, because I understand that slicing the string will make a copy (very expensive in my case). In other words, can I specify a start point for an iterator over a string?

Comment: Oh - I'm mainly using python 3, if that makes  difference. But would be interested to know for 2.7 as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In python3 `range` is an generator, and not a list. That means that the following code will not require excessive memory:

```
for i in range(start_pos, len(my_string)):
   print(my_string[i])
```

If you'd rather use an iterator over `my_string` then you need to write it yourself:

```
def iter_starting_at(start_pos, string):
    for i in range(start_pos, len(string)):
        yield string[i]

for character in iter_starting_at(start_pos, my_string):
    print(character)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do it using string indexes, like it's list:

```
for i in xrange(100, 200):
    print(s[i])
```

Comment: Sounds slow to use an index every time. But maybe it's just as quick as an iterator. `range(100,100000000)` looks worryingly intensive to me, although again I may be wrong because the range result is probably an iterator, not an actual list.

Comment: In Python 3, `range` is an iterator ... In Python 2.7 it is not, and you should use `xrange`

Comment: @donkopotamus thanks, I've replaced range to xrange.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) as follows:

```
from itertools import islice

for c in islice(my_str, start, stop):
    print(c)
```

Comment: Note that `islice` will actually iterate over the first `start_pos` characters doing nothing though. String indexing will be faster for a large start position.

Comment: @poke, absolutely right. I tend to forget this nuance in its behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating indexes into the string, we could use `itertools.islice`, which returns an iterator over a slice.

```
for c in itertools.islice(my_enormous_string, start_pos):
    ...
```

Comment: Note that `islice` will actually iterate over the first `start_pos` characters doing nothing though. String indexing will be faster for a large start position.

Comment: +1 for using the islice built in. But looking at the code this just does a range operator anyway, and is not optimised for large start positions as @poke says.